# Input Validation in JS

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation, input

why my last if condition is not working to show validity error, if user input no value. Actually i am beginner in js making calculator as practice. I shall be very thankful if anyone could resolve it.

```
 function calc()
            {
                let n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
                let n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
                let oper = document.getElementById('operators').value;
                
                
                if(oper === '+')
                {
                    document.getElementById('result').value = n1+n2;
                }
                
                if(oper === '-')
                {
                    document.getElementById('result').value = n1-n2;
                }
                
                if(oper === '/')
                {
                    document.getElementById('result').value = n1/n2;
                }
                
                if(oper === 'X')
                {
                    document.getElementById('result').value = n1*n2;
                }
                 if(n1=="" || n2==""){
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="invalid input";
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: You are probably checking on the letter 'X' (caps) and you are probably using letter 'x' or '*' to do the multiplication.

Comment: parseFloat("")=NaN and NaN==="" is false so in your case you will not see an error, you can try this if(!n1 || !n2)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it happens because it reacts to the condition next to the last one where you have `n1=="" || n2==""`